# Pivoting multiple rows based on sorted values in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am working with a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B'],'X':[1.2,2.1,3.8,4.5,5.8,6.2,7,8.2],'Y':[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80],'IsTrue':[1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1],'IdxVar':[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]})
df["DistanceToIdx"] = np.sqrt((df.X - df.X[df.groupby('ID')['IdxVar'].transform('idxmax')].reset_index(drop=True))**2 \
                        +(df.Y - df.Y[df.groupby('ID')['IdxVar'].transform('idxmax')].reset_index(drop=True))**2)
```

I am trying to create a new df that has a single row per ID value, based on `IdxVar`.  Simple enough

```
newdf = df.loc[df.IdxVar==1,:]
```

I want my new columns to be some `X0_1, X0_2, X1_1, X0_2`, where the `Xi_j` can be seen as the `X` values `for i = IsTrue` (either 0 or 1) and the `j` indicates the sorted index of `DistanceToIdx` (`X0_1` indicates the `X` value in a given ID that has `IsTrue = 0` and the lowest `DistanceToIdx`).

I can do this through `groupby()`:

```
groupdf = df.groupby('ID')

for name,group in groupdf:
    for i in range(2):

        newdf.loc[newdf.ID==name, 'X0_{}'.format(i+1)] = \
            group.sort_values(by=['IsTrue','DistanceToIdx'],ascending=True)['X'].values[i]

        newdf.loc[newdf.ID==name, 'X1_{}'.format(i+1)] = \
            group.sort_values(by=['IsTrue','DistanceToIdx'],ascending=True)['X'].values[i+2]
```

This gives the desired output, but if I want to apply it to more variables then shown here and then loop through 100,000 groups, my loop is taking way too long.

I was wondering if there would be a way to speed this up with just the groupby function.  My initial thought was just to figure out the pivot function, but since I want to order my new columns based on an existing row, I am not too confident based on the documentation that it would work.

Answer (score 1):

As you already created `newdf`. I come up with solution using `nsmallest` to get 2 smallest values of each group, `unstack` and flatten multiindex columns. Finally, merge back to `newdf`

```
df1 = (df.set_index('X').groupby(['ID', 'IsTrue']).DistanceToIdx.nsmallest(2).
          reset_index(level=-1).drop('DistanceToIdx', 1))
s = df1.groupby(level=[0,1]).cumcount().add(1)
df2 = df1.set_index(s, append=True).unstack([1,2]).sort_index(level=2, axis=1)
df2.columns = df2.columns.map('{0[0]}{0[1]}_{0[2]}'.format)

df_final = newdf.merge(df2.reset_index(), on='ID')


Out[239]:

  ID    X   Y  IsTrue  IdxVar  DistanceToIdx  X0_1  X1_1  X0_2  X1_2
0  A  1.2  10       1       1            0.0   3.8   1.2   4.5   2.1
1  B  8.2  80       1       1            0.0   7.0   8.2   6.2   5.8
```

Comment: This seems to be working pretty well on my larger dataset!  Followup:  if I want to extend in this set to X and Y,  is it as simple as just doing the initial set_indes(['X','Y'])?  Or will the multiindex be trickier ?

Comment: It is pretty much the same. Besides `set_indes(['X','Y'])`, you need to add and change some levels as.:  `...reset_index(level=[-1,-2])...`

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) 
to create the  `j` indexes
and be able to pivot the table ([`DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html)) differentiating in the 4 columns.
Then simply attach it to the frame where `IdxVar==1` using [`DataFrame.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)

```
new_df=df.copy()
#creating columns to pivot_table and set the name of the columns
new_df['id2']=df.groupby(['ID','IsTrue']).IsTrue.cumcount()+1

#Selecting IDxVar1 --->df1
df1=df[df.IdxVar.eq(1)]

#Using pivot_table
#new_df=new_df.sort_values(by=['IsTrue','DistanceToIdx'],ascending=True)
df2=new_df.pivot_table(index='ID',columns=['id2','IsTrue'],values='X')

#join both dataframes
new_df=df1.join(df2,on='ID')

#creating the names of columns
new_df.columns =df.columns.tolist() + [f'X{i}_{j}' for j,i in df2.columns]
print(new_df)
```

**Output**

```
  ID    X   Y  IsTrue  IdxVar  DistanceToIdx  X0_1  X1_1  X0_2  X1_2
0  A  1.2  10       1       1            0.0   3.8   1.2   4.5   2.1
7  B  8.2  80       1       1            0.0   7.0   8.2   6.2   5.8
```

Comment: So how does that sort by the 'DistanceToIdx' variable?

Comment: I think it is not necessary to order here. Since pivot table orders in the correct order. Just as when using groupby the data is sorted because sort = True by default in the groupby method. Have you got any error with this code?

Comment: I have updated my solution. You could use `new_df=new_df.sort_values(by=['IsTrue','DistanceToIdx'],ascending=True)`